# Why the enclosing tuples in decoded SSL certificates in Python?

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate

This is a sample output of [ssl.SSLSocket.getpeercert](http://python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLSocket.getpeercert), taken from the documentation.

```
{'issuer': ((('countryName', 'IL'),),
            (('organizationName', 'StartCom Ltd.'),),
            (('organizationalUnitName',
              'Secure Digital Certificate Signing'),),
            (('commonName',
              'StartCom Class 2 Primary Intermediate Server CA'),)),
 'notAfter': 'Nov 22 08:15:19 2013 GMT',
 'notBefore': 'Nov 21 03:09:52 2011 GMT',
 'serialNumber': '95F0',
 'subject': ((('description', '571208-SLe257oHY9fVQ07Z'),),
             (('countryName', 'US'),),
             (('stateOrProvinceName', 'California'),),
             (('localityName', 'San Francisco'),),
             (('organizationName', 'Electronic Frontier Foundation, Inc.'),),
             (('commonName', '*.eff.org'),),
             (('emailAddress', 'hostmaster@eff.org'),)),
 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', '*.eff.org'), ('DNS', 'eff.org')),
 'version': 3}
```

I wonder what the purpose of the one-element tuples in `issuer` and `subject` is. Could a subject have several properties in the same row?

Comment: Ostensibly - yes, some fields can have multiple entries. For instance you can have multiple common names. I would suspect that to make parsing simpler they treat all key-value pairs as potentially having multiple fields to avoid having to make the checks tailored to each datatype?

Comment: See @hop answer. Even in that case they seem to be 1-tuple rows.

Answer (score 0):

The nested structure probably comes directly from the [RFC 5280](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt), section 4.1.2.4.:

```
RelativeDistinguishedName ::=
    SET SIZE (1..MAX) OF AttributeTypeAndValue

AttributeTypeAndValue ::= SEQUENCE {
    type     AttributeType,
    value    AttributeValue }
```

Well, maybe not.

I guess it's possible to encounter several instances of one attribute type (`locality`, for example), but rather unlikely. Depending on the use case I'd ignore subsequent values of the same type and log a warning to help with debugging.

If you think it's worth your time, you can read all about it in the X.500 standards, but for what it's worth, here is how it actually behaves:

The default `openssl.cnf` contains this:

```
[ req_distinguished_name ]
0.organizationName      = Organization Name (eg, company)
0.organizationName_default  = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd

# we can do this but it is not needed normally :-)
#1.organizationName      = Second Organization Name (eg, company)
#1.organizationName_default  = World Wide Web Pty Ltd
```

And here is the result in Python if you activate the second `o`:

```
{'notAfter': 'Apr 27 20:03:12 2014 GMT',
 'subject': ((('countryName', u'AU'),),
             (('stateOrProvinceName', u'Some-State'),),
             (('organizationName', u'Internet Widgits Pty Ltd'),),
             (('organizationName', u'World Wide Web Pty Ltd'),),
             (('commonName', u'www.example.com'),),
             (('emailAddress', u'foo@example.com'),))}
```

Comment: I still don't get it. Even if there were two `localityName` properties, wouldn't they be something like `'subject': ((('localityName', 'Madrid')), (('localityName', 'Paris')))`?

Comment: @ntrrgc: yeah. but honestly, why does it matter?

Comment: Well, I try to make sense of the API. I could just do `subject = [x[0] for x in cert['subject']]`.

Comment: That they should have used tuples of tuples of tuples instead of tuples of tuples for a reason.

Comment: @ntrrgc: shoulda, woulda, coulda. x.500 is complicated and full of cruft… no reason to assume reason. i created a certificate to settle the matter, i hope.